# questions about using $.ajax() to post request in codepen.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

well, codepen.io is really an awesome front end designing web, but somehow I meet some problems. I try to use $.ajax() to request the JSON from [weatherapi](http://openweathermap.org/current) in [myworks](https://codepen.io/YangYining/pen/oLyXvy?editors=1011) in codepen.io

here are my codes

```
 function clickButton(){

 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",

 url:"api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&APPID=c7294a560e0aac2d8389242ba90f4a6a",
 dataType: "jsonp",

 success: function(response){
  console.log(response);
 },
 error: function(xhr,status,error){
  console.log(status);
 }
});

}
```

i have used a lot of ways to test whether this url can be used, and just find that it works well. However, i cant figure out why this ajax request always fail......

I have read about another question that similar to my situation, the solution is to add "http://" before the url, but it seems that add it before doesnt work for me......

Comment: You're missing the `http://` in your URL

Comment: it seems that it still doesnt work. .....

Comment: this is restricted by CORS.

Comment: @DanielA.White Looks like OP is trying to use JSONP to circumvent CORS restrictions. But the [docs](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/) seems to indicate that OP needs to add a few more config fields (the jsonp attribute, that specifies the name of the callback supplied by openweathermap, assuming they support jsonp?).

Answer (score 0):

I used the same `api` in my project. You have to add `https://` for it to work. This is very important or it wont work.